# Why sometimes the cookie won't be neither unset nor overwrite?

Tags: php, cookies

Today I've faced with a strange problem. I have a code which sometimes writes something in the cookie, and sometimes overwrites it.

My code works as well when that cookie isn't exists. I mean, when I clear all browser's cookies and execute my code, all fine. But after an unknown while, that cookie will be constant, fixed and firm. I mean it will not be overwrite anymore, it will not be even unset.

Here is my code: *(however it works totally as well at first)*

```
.
.
    if( isset( $_GET['u'] ) && ( $_GET['u'] == 'true' || $_GET['u'] == 'false' ) ){
        if( isset($_COOKIE['qanda_unanswered_status']) ) {
            if ( $_COOKIE['qanda_unanswered_status'] != $_GET['u'] ){
                setcookie("qanda_unanswered_status", $_GET['u'], 2147483647);   
            }
        } else {
            setcookie("qanda_unanswered_status", $_GET['u'], 2147483647);   
        }
    }
.
.

    if (isset($_GET['u']) && in_array($_GET['u'], ['true', 'false']) && (!isset($_COOKIE['qanda_unanswered_status']) || $_COOKIE['qanda_unanswered_status'] != $_GET['u']) ) {
        setcookie("qanda_unanswered_status", $_GET['u'], 2147483647);
        $_COOKIE['qanda_unanswered_status'] = $_GET['u'];
    }
.
.
```

It's all about cookies. Anyway, do you have any clue, how can I debug this problem? When a cookie will be constant forever? I mean even `unset($_COOKIE['sth'])` isn't able to destroy it.

Do you have any clue of such a problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `unset()` to remove a cookie, you need to set the expiration in the past for example:

```
setcookie("qanda_unanswered_status", "", time() - 3600); // one hour ago
```

Then the cookie will be deleted on the browser.

Comment: Is it working fine now? Can you accept the answer if so, thnx!